# How to debug cinnamon applet?

Tags: javascript, linux, debugging, ide, cinnamon

I wish to write a cinnamon applet.  These are based in JavaScript.  The code I wish to write changes services (turning them on and off, similar to [WebDeveloperMenuApplet](https://bitbucket.org/infiniteshroom/cinnamon-webdevelopermenuapplet/src/e254b5bbd25b57864d9e04efb9ead9a1599dd2e1/web-developer-menu%40infiniteshroom/applet.js?at=master)).  I don't expect the debugging for the service start/stop/restart to work, but I was wondering how I would debug the menu items and the calls to the functions.  I also wish to write a configuration applet that would involve some more complex coding or calls to a external server.

Is it possible to load this into a web browser or is there a better way to debugging this?  I don't know where the imports command is pulling so I am not sure how to duplicate this in a web browser.

Currently using IntelliJ IDEA as IDE, but quite will to switch to anything for this project.

Answer (score 20):

Your best bet here is the old trick of printing messages to the terminal.  Use `global.log(...)` for it, the lines are sent to the `~/.cinnamon/glass.log` file, to watch them just do:

```sh
tail -f ~/.cinnamon/glass.log
```

Also, as stated by [@elParaguayo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3087339/elparaguayo), type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring the Cinnamon prompt, type in `lg` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to show the Looking Glass Debugger topmost dialog, there you can evaluate expressions by typing them in the `Exec:` input box and watching the results listed in the `Results` tab.

Comment: There is a shortcut to toggle the Looking Glass Debugger: `Win+L`. And also as mentioned by @lestcape
's answer, `~/.xsession-errors` is also a file that contains useful debug informations.

Comment: As of Cinnamon 5.4.9, the `Win+L` stopped working for me. Alt+F2 `lg` still does.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is over a year old now, but I came across it as I was trying to write my own applet so I though I'd share my experiences.

In terms of debugging, I'm not sure these can be done in a browser. I debugged mine by updating my code, re-activating the applet in Cinnamon and then looking at the error log (`Alt`+`F2` and then type `lg`).

Not a great solution at all, but it's the only solution I've found.

Comment: How do you reactivate the applet? I find that even removing it and re-adding it to the panel doesn't reload it.

Comment: Super+L to start "looking glass" and then restart cinnamon. Takes only half a second for me.

Answer (score 5):

Use the browser is not possible. You need to read:

1. `~/.xsession-errors` (because not all errors can appear as a cinnamon errors if you interact with other system applications) or you also can read the terminal output of cinnamon (same as xsession-errors, but will be update dynamically). Execute "cinnamon --replace" to enable the output mode, is possible that this will required to be execute more than one time.
2. `~/.cinnamon/glass.log` or you can use Melange - Cinnamon Debugger.
   Just click on cinnamon panel, TroubleShoot and find the application.

Comment: I needed to restart Cinnamon to read the updated version of the applet (even though I removed/added the applet, it did not help).
I found the "Restart Cinnamon" applet for that (can be downloaded at Applets -> Download) [link](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/14).
But I guess this is brute force, so if anyone knows how to do it better then please share.

Comment: @Attila123: I found typing this at the command line works: `dbus-send --session --dest=org.Cinnamon.LookingGlass --type=method_call /org/Cinnamon/LookingGlass org.Cinnamon.LookingGlass.ReloadExtension string:'app@domain' string:'APPLET'` (where `app@doman` is the UUID for the applet, as defined in metadata.json). Source: https://gist.github.com/hyOzd/35e913db620b3ba086fb