# Log to a file from Javascript code executed with no console window

Tags: javascript, applet, introspection, cinnamon

Working on a Cinnamon applet ([Example](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/tree/edbfb67ff3d3286a314f3b74e0cea27f822af11b/files/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/favorites%40cinnamon.org)). These use Javascript interpreted by the [cjs](https://github.com/linuxmint/cjs) interpreter and run without a console window.

How can I log something to a file or to a console from within the code I am working on?

I can not put test code into a separate Javascript file and run it with `cjs <the file>`, because there I do not have access to modules provided to applets by Cinnamon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Logging

To log from the javascript:

```js
global.log('my message')
```

To inspect things, including objects with possibly circular references, define this function:

```js
const inspect = (function() {
    function replace_circular_references(show_private_keys) {
        let fullpaths = new Map(), cleanpaths= new Map(), rootobject = null
        return function(key, value) {
            let decycled; {
                if (!show_private_keys && key.startsWith('_')) return undefined
                let path = fullpaths.get(this) + (
                    Array.isArray(this) ? `[${key}]` : `.${key}` )
                let is_complex = value === Object(value)
                if (is_complex) fullpaths.set(value, path)
                let cleanpath = cleanpaths.get(value) || ''
                if (!cleanpath && is_complex)
                    cleanpaths.set(value, path.replace(/undefined\.\.?/, ''))
                decycled = cleanpath ?
                    `${cleanpath[0] == '[' ? '(this)' : '(this).'}${cleanpath}`
                    : value
                if (rootobject === null) rootobject = value
                else if (decycled === rootobject) { decycled = "(this)" }
            }
            return decycled
        }
    }
    return function (nameofthing, thing, show_private_keys=true, fold=null) {
        try {
            let thingrepr; {
                thingrepr = JSON.stringify(
                    thing, replace_circular_references(show_private_keys), '\t'
                ).replace(
                    /"([^\n"]+)"[:] /g, "$1: "  // prettify keys
                ).replace(
                    /"(\(this\)[^\n"]*)"/g, "$1"  // prettify circular refs
                )
                if (fold !== null) {  // maybe fold away some things
                    for (const key of fold) {
                        thingrepr = thingrepr.replace(
                            new RegExp(`^([ ]*)${key}: [{][^]*?\\n\\1[}]`, 'gm'),
                            "$1" + key + ": {...}"
                        ).replace(
                            new RegExp(`^([ ]*)${key}: \\[[^]*?\\n\\1\\]`, 'gm'),
                            "$1" + key + ": [...]"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            global.log(`\n${nameofthing} = ${thingrepr}`)
        } catch (error) {
            global.log(`${nameofthing} = (oops, can not do that)`)
            global.log(error)
            global.log(error.message)
        }
    }
})()
```

and use it like so:

```js
inspect('myobject', myobject)
```

or like so, to hide keys starting with underscores:

```js
inspect('myobject', myobject, false)
```

or like so, to fold specific keys you are not interested in:

```js
inspect('myobject', myobject, true, ['key1', 'key2', ...])
```

## Viewing the log

To view the logged messages, either use the console or a GUI (or both).

### Using the console

```bash
tail -f ~/.xsession-errors
```

Or, prior to Cinnamon 3.8.8:

```bash
tail -f ~/.cinnamon/glass.log
```

Press `ctrl` + `c` to abort the logging.

To reload the applet:

```bash
dbus-send --session --dest=org.Cinnamon.LookingGlass -- \
type=method_call /org/Cinnamon/LookingGlass \
org.Cinnamon.LookingGlass.ReloadExtension \
string:'your-applet-uuid' \
string:'APPLET'
```

where `your-applet-uuid` is the value of the `uuid` key in *metadata.json*.

It is simplest to run this command from another console, so you do not have to abort the logging.

### Using a GUI

Cinnamon also has the Melange-Cinnamon debugger. To open it:

- Right click on the task bar and select *Troubleshoot* → *Looking Glass*.
- Alternatively, press `Win key` + `L`.
- Alternatively, press `Alt` + `F2` → type "lg" → `Enter`.

The logging happens under the *log* tab.

To reload the code of the applet, find it under the *extensions* tab, right click → *reload code*.

To reload Cinnamon and do other things, use the *Actions* button.

The debugger has a small bug, sometimes the scroll bar disappears when long stuff gets logged. To get it back, press `ctrl` + `Home` and  `ctrl` + `End`.

To be able to have the debugger window in the background, right click its title bar.

## Kudos

- [`refReplacer` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61749783/1658543)
- [Prettyprinting JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46862258/1658543)
- [Cinnamon log location](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214476/430002)
- [Reload applet from console](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3186#issuecomment-457132113)
- [Melange-Cinnamon Debugger](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467319/430002)
- [tail command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28512708)
- [Alt + F2 shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23061908/1658543)