# Developing task bar applets for Cinnamon: How to reload the code?

Tags: javascript, applet, cinnamon

Working on a Cinnamon Javascript applet ([Example](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/tree/edbfb67ff3d3286a314f3b74e0cea27f822af11b/files/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/favorites%40cinnamon.org)).

How can I reload the code, so that the applet in the task bar reflects the changes I make in the Javascript?

Manually removing the applet from the task bar and then re-adding it seems not to reload the code, and is cumbersome anyway. I have to log off and log in again to see the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72709300/1658543):

**Use the Melange-Cinnamon debugger.** To open it:

- Right click on the task bar and select *Troubleshoot* → *Looking Glass*.
- Alternatively, press `Win key` + `L`.
- Alternatively, press `Alt` + `F2` → type "lg" → `Enter`.

Reload the code of the applet by finding the applet under the *extensions* tab, right click → *reload code*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reload the applet through command line, using

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.Cinnamon.LookingGlass --type=method_call /org/Cinnamon/LookingGlass org.Cinnamon.LookingGlass.ReloadExtension string:'appletUUID' string:'APPLET'
```